# How to find Total Number of Checkboxs - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to count total number of checkbox present?

this is html source code generating by page..

```
<tr> 
  <td>
    <span style="padding-left:15px;">
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_8" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AddControl1$cat$lstCat$8"/>
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddControl1_lstCat_8">Item 1</label>
    </span>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
  <td>
    <span style="padding-left:15px;">
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_9" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AddControl1$cat$lstCat$8"/>
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddControl1_lstCat_9">Item 2</label>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
  <td>
    <span style="padding-left:15px;">
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_10" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AddControl1$cat$lstCat$8"/>
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddControl1_lstCat_10">Item 3</label>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (or something similar to it) should work.

```
// WARNING: Untested code. Locator syntax may be
// slightly incorrect.
// Using C#, but other languages are similar.
// Assume driver is a valid IWebDriver instance.
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> checkboxes = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));
Console.WriteLine(checkboxes.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int countedCheckBoxes = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int CountCheckBoxes(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        int countedCheckBoxes = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).Count;
        return countedCheckBoxes;
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.